# Convert MyList(,) of Object to String array with LINQ

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, visual-studio

I have a little problem with the performance of one of my applications, basically:

An external system gives me a big structure as an `Object(,)`.

This structure only has *an column per row*.

```
MyData(0,0) = 'COL1-ROW1 | COL2-ROW1 | COL3-ROW1'
MyData(1,0) = 'COL1-ROW2 | COL2-ROW2 | COL3-ROW2'
MyData(2,0) = 'COL1-ROW3 | COL2-ROW3 | COL3-ROW3'
MyData(3,0) = 'COL1-ROW4 | COL2-ROW4 | COL3-ROW4'

MyData(0,1) ' Doesn't exists.
```

There are some method in LINQ to convert this structure to an one dimensional array of strings?

It would be awesome if you could divide by columns, given a specific character.

Something like this:

```
NewData(0,0) = COL1-ROW1
NewData(0,1) = COL2-ROW1
NewData(0,2) = COL3-ROW1
NewData(1,0) = COL1-ROW2
...
NewData(3,2) = COL3-ROW3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer from myself; here my solution:

```
Dim vMyData(1000, 0) As Object

For x = 0 To 1000
    vMyData(x, 0) = String.Format("ROW{0}COL1|ROW{0}COL2|ROW{0}COL3|ROW{0}COL4", x)
Next

Dim vQuery = From TempResult In vMyData
         Select Value = TempResult.ToString.Split("|")

Dim vMyNewArray As New ArrayList(vQuery.ToArray)
```

[image]

Now; exists some method to trim each value of the `Split("|")`?

[UPDATE TO THE PREVIOUS QUESTION]:

```
From TempResult In vMyData Select Value = Array.ConvertAll(TempResult.ToString.Split("|"), Function(vVal) vVal.ToString.Trim)
```

Comment: You could use the `ForEach()` on `Value`. Do something like `Value.Foreach(Sub(s) s.Trim())`.

Comment: Ooops, sorry just saw that `Value` is actually in the query, so that wouldn't work. But you can execute the trim `vQuery` afterwards. You need to convert it to a list first though using `ToList()`.

Comment: @yu_ominae: It's some method to trim all values at the same time?. I tried to make it in LINQ by this reason.

Comment: Well, it's a linQ extension, so after you get 'vQuery', on the next Line you can call `vQuery.ToList().ForEach(Sub(s) s.ForEach(Sub(ss) ss.Trim()))`. That will loop through each item in `vQuery` and loop through each string in the item and trim it for you. But it's just two `For Each` loop rolled into one line...

Comment: I make it this and works very well: `From TempResult In vMyData Select Value = Array.ConvertAll(TempResult.ToString.Split("|"), Function(vVal) vVal.ToString.Trim)`

Comment: Yes, I realised that on my way home for lunch as well :) I think you could also just do: `... Select Value = TempResult.ToString.Split("|").Select(Function(s) s.Split())` in your previous code. But I haven't tried this. Think it should work as well though.

Comment: Not sure if my comments actually helped at all, but you're welcome :)